# Build json from ValueObjects in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

i was wondering how i can build a json response from a value object?

**Situation?**
I want to return clear json, only the field i need in the front-end. Which means: All associations should be included in the json. But again: only the fields I need. This i why i would like to use a special value object (defining the field) on top of my models.

**Problem?**
Is this a good idea? How to build value objects (VOs) with rails?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. Look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html):

Here is an example:

```
konata.to_json(:only => [ :id, :name ])
# => {"id": 1, "name": "Konata Izumi"}
```

As you're talking about associations:

```
konata.to_json(:include => :posts)
# => {"id": 1, "name": "Konata Izumi", "age": 16,
  "created_at": "2006/08/01", "awesome": true,
  "posts": [{"id": 1, "author_id": 1, "title": "Welcome to the weblog"},
            {"id": 2, author_id: 1, "title": "So I was thinking"}]}
```

Comment: `konata.to_json(:include => :posts)` what does that mean? is `posts` a relationship of `konata` ?

Answer (score 1):

This one sounds interesting:
http://fabrik42.github.com/acts_as_api/